# returning names assigned with different values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below.

```
name    country gender  
Ada      US      1
Aby      UK      0
Alan     US      0
Eli      US      1
Eddy     US      1
Bing     NW      0
Bing     US      1
Eli      UK      0
Eli      US      0
Alan     US      1
Ada      UK      0
```

I am hoping to return a list containing names assigned with different country or names assigned with different gender.

For example

```
Eli UK
Eli US
```

Also,

```
   Eli 1
   Eli 0
```

I used

```
groupby('name')['gender']
```

are there any transform command or other command that will help me return such list?

Comment: Please show the full expected output to us

Answer (score 0):

You can use transform:

```
df[df.groupby('name')['gender'].transform(lambda x: x.nunique()>1)]
df[df.groupby('name')['country'].transform(lambda x: x.nunique()>1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.loc` accessor `:` to slice the columns. chain `drop_duplicates()` to drop any duplicates

```
d(df.loc[df.name=='Eli', :'country':]).drop_duplicates(keep='last')

   name country
7  Eli      UK
8  Eli      US

(df.loc[df.name=='Eli', ['name','gender']]).drop_duplicates(keep='last')
 name  gender
3  Eli       1
8  Eli       0
```